# External Monitors go black when streaming YoutubeTV on Firefox

Tags: windows-10, firefox, multiple-monitors

For some reason when I try to stream YoutubeTV on Firefox it will cause my external monitors to go black and only display my laptop.

The laptop however still shows the two monitors as existing and connected if I go to Display settings, and if I close the YoutubeTV page they come right back.

My guess is that YoutubeTV has something they use to try to stop screen recorders and somehow it thinks my monitors are a screen recorder or something.

Has anyone else seen this problem or have any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Does your laptop display go black also? Connection is with Wifi? It could be your browser is stuck in the buffer zone if both both screens appear black. It may also be the youtube page itself.

Comment: No, the laptop screen operates completely as normal.

Comment: How are you connecting to the television? HDMI, DVI, or other? Have you tried unplugging the connection to the TV and plugging it back in? You really should edit your question, add what methods you have tried, this would help solve the mystery.